# C/C++ FLAC tagging library

Tags: c++, c, stream, tagging

Is there any C/C++ FLAC tagging library that work on streams? Wherever I look I only find ones that work on files. It's kinda weird to me - why use something limited like file instead of more abstract stream. Well, maybe I'm just spoiled by managed languages neatness (I'm more of a Java guy, but this time I need unmanaged code solution).

Comment: I don't think it's logical for an audio tagger to work on streams. How do you tag a stream unless you have read all of it in a buffer first?

Comment: What do managed languages have to do with tagging streams?  Can you post an example of a FLAC library and how, exactly, it does not address your needs?

Comment: It is a common misconception that there's something inherently wrong with files.  You do *not* read from a disk when you read a file, you read from memory.  Implemented by the file system cache.  A stream is a so-so abstraction for a file, it like to pretend that seeking isn't implemented.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with files, but it's wrong to assume that data will always be stored in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with any FLAC libraries, but the [reference FLAC library](http://flac.sourceforge.net/) supports an [interface for custom I/O](http://flac.sourceforge.net/api/group__flac__callbacks.html).  This allows you to write a small stub that will convert I/O calls to a custom data source, which needn't be a file.

It seems to require capacity to seek, though.  If that is the case, then you might not be able to wrap a socket without a high-level protocol that allows you to seek.